# How to solve this error "connection to local host failled " while deploying my django project on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am making a Facebook app using Django and want to deploy my project on Heroku. While deploying my project I am putting my important data in a .env file using decouple module. My settings.py file looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
        'USER':  config('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD' : config('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST' : config('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': '5432',

    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT  =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Default primary key field type
```

and my .env file looks like this

```
SECRET_KEY=#####

DB_NAME=#######
DB_USER=########
DB_PASSWORD=#######
DB_HOST=#########
```

and I am facing this error:

```
OperationalError at /login
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
Request Method:    POST
Request URL:    https://facebook-django-akhil.herokuapp.com/login
Django Version:    4.0.6
Exception Type:    OperationalError
Exception Value:
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
Exception Location:    /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/init.py, line 122, in connect
Python Executable:    /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version:    3.10.5
Python Path:
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python310.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 14 Jul 2022 13:44:31 +0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also create a database to go with your app. Since you're already using Heroku, you can use Heroku Postgres as an app addon.

To create the database for your app on the free tier:

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
```

Now, Heroku will automatically inject the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable for your app, so you'll need to use that information in your app to connect to the database:

```py
# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url

DATABASES = {
  'default': dj_database_url.config()
}
```

For your local development environment, you can remove `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER` and the other `DB_XXX` environment variables from your `.env` and add `DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@localhost/dbname` to your `.env` instead, filling in the correct username, password, and dbname, of course.

Comment: I have given config vars (key-value pairs) but it is showing the same error.

Comment: The problem seems to be that your code is trying to connect to a Postgres database on `localhost`, which is incorrect. In Heroku, there will not be a database running on `localhost`. The database host info should come from DB_HOST. What value did you give Heroku for `DB_HOST`?

Comment: I have given "DB_HOST=localhost" now what can I do to solve this issue is there any reference videos for that?

Comment: Ah, that is the problem. You must create a Postgres database that Heroku can connect to and then tell your app how to connect to that database. The easiest way to create a Postgres database for your app to use is to use Heroku's Postgres service as an addon for your app. I'll update the answer to include that.